# Show that $f_{\alpha}(t)$ is a p.d.f.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\displaystyle \phi(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$,$t\in \Bbb R$ be the standard normal density function and $\displaystyle \Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(t)\,dt$ be the standard normal distribution function. Let $f_{\alpha}(t)=2\phi(t)\Phi(\alpha t)$,$t\in \Bbb R$
where $\alpha \in \Bbb R$. Show that $f_{\alpha}$ is a probability density function.

we have $\Phi'(x)=\phi(x)$. We have to show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\alpha}(t)\,dt=1$. I tried by integration by-parts but I got the value is $0$. Dose there any other process or where is my mistake.?

**Edit :**

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\alpha}(t)dt= 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\Phi(\alpha t)\,dt=2\left[\Phi(\alpha t)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\,dt\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\alpha\Phi'(\alpha t).\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\,dt\right]\,dt=2[\Phi(\infty)-\Phi(-\infty)]-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha\phi(\alpha t)\,dt=\cdots=0$

Comment: Can you show your steps? Like, the integration by parts.

Comment: @Anna See edit please...

Comment: See [Integration by polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). This is the method I have seen most often in probability books.

Comment: The integration by parts formula in your Edit simply does not make sense, please review this topic seriously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A probabilistic interpretation: consider $(X,Y)$ i.i.d. standard normal, then $\Phi(at)=P(X<at)$ and $\varphi$ is the PDF of $Y$ hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\varphi(t)\Phi(at)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\varphi(t)P(X<at)dt=2P(X<aY)=2P(Z<0)$$ where $Z=X-aY$ is centered normal with nonzero variance. Every centered normal distribution is symmetric hence $P(Z<0)=\frac12$. This shows that the integral on the LHS is $1$, as desired.

Comment: Why is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(t)P(X<t)dt=P(X<Y)$? I tried $P(X<Y)=E(1_{\{X<Y\}})=\int_{\Omega} 1_{\{X<Y\}} dP$ and then using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_Change-of-variables_formula) and Fubini, but I do not know the distribution of $1_{\{X<Y\}}$.

Comment: Because $\varphi$ is the PDF of $Y$ and because $(X,Y)$ is independent hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi(t)P(X<t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi(t)\int_{-\infty}^tdP_X(x)dt=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\mathbf 1_{x<t}dP_X(x)dP_Y(t)=P(X<Y)$$

Comment: Thank you, it can be so easy if you know what to do... And in the last equality you used independence.

Answer (score 1):

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\alpha}(t)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{d\alpha}f_{\alpha}(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(2\phi(t)\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha t}\phi(s)\,ds\right)dt \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2t\phi(t)\phi(\alpha t)\,dt \\
&=0
\end{align*}
$

since the integrand is odd. Therefore $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\alpha}(t)\,dt$ is equal to its initial value at $\alpha=0$ which is $1$.

Comment: At $\alpha=0$ , the value of the integral becomes $\sqrt{2/\pi}$. How it is $1$ ?

Comment: @S717717 $f_0(t)=2\phi(t)\phi(0)=2\phi(t)(1/2)=\phi(t)$ which integrates to $1$.

Comment: How $\phi(0)=1/2$ ?

Comment: @S717717 My mistake, that should have been $\Phi(0)$ so it's $f_0(t)=2\phi(t)\Phi(0)$.